# ¿Cómo asignar a una aplicación para que utilice una determinada interfaz de red?

Tags: windows, redes

Tengo el siguiente problema, por cuestiones del trabajo debo estar conectado vía LAN y vía Wifi, en LAN para acceder a la red empresarial(Conexiona a equipos, BD, etc.) en esta red el Internet es muy limitado, a su vez trabajo en proyectos Java que descargan ficheros de Internet, esto lo hago con la wifi, pero debo desconectarme de la LAN, la duda es hay forma de decirle a Windows que para algunos programas use la LAN y otros la wifi???

Comment: Que version de windows utilizas? yo en windows 7 tengo configurada la conexión a través de la placa wifi para que tenga prioridad por sobre la placa de red cableada, por lo tanto para navegar utilizo la conexión de la placa wifi, pero para todo lo demás (impresoras, carpetas compartidas, etc) la red cableada. esto se serviria no?

Comment: Deshabilitas la interfaz que no quieras y listo! te toma 2 minutos, no necesitas saber de programación para eso

Comment: Además de las respuestas que puedas recibir, ¿consideraste usar un proxy localmente?

Answer (score 2):

Interesante pregunta, tuve que investigar un poco para responderla.

Te comento que esto en Windows, se puede realizar con una aplicación que intercepta las llamadas de red de las aplicaciones y permite forzar que la aplicación utilice una interfaz de red específica (Wi-Fi o LAN).

La aplicación para realizar esto se llama [ForceBindIP](http://www.r1ch.net/stuff/forcebindip/) y funciona de la siguiente manera:

Desde el símbolo del sistema (CMD) escribe:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\ForceBindIP\ForceBindIP.exe" 192.168.0.100 “"C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"”
```

En el ejemplo, ejecutará Google Chrome con la conexión de la interfaz de red que contenga la IP 192.168.0.100. La IP del ejemplo, debe ser reemplazada por la que tiene asignada la interfaz que querés usar.

**Si la IP es dinámica**, tendrás que sustituir la IP por la clave que identifica a la red en el registro de Windows.

Para averiguar cuál es la clave que identifica a la interfaz de red que vas usar, hay que seguir los siguientes pasos:

> **1** - Clic en el botón Inicio -> Ejecutar (Win + R).
>
> **2** - Escribir regedit y navegar hasta la siguiente clave: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters\Interfaces
>
> **3** - Navega por las claves observando el valor **DhcpIPAddress** para localizar cuál es el que tiene la misma IP que la interfaz de red que
>   vas a asignarle a la aplicación. Una vez localizada la misma IP, podés
>   copiar el nombre dando clic arriba de la clave con el botón derecho,
>   dando clic en cambiar nombre y copiando todo. El valor es algo similar
>   a esto: **{AF29AE03-558A-4EFC-F576-D10EGE20463F}**
>
> **4** - Una vez copiado todo el valor, debes pegarlo de la siguiente forma:
>
> ```
> "C:\Program Files (x86)\ForceBindIP\ForceBindIP.exe" {AF29AE03-558A-4EFC-F576-D10EGE20463F} “"C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"”
> ```

También podés agregar algunas entradas al menú contextual (Menú que aparece al hacer clic derecho sobre una aplicación) y de esta forma, no tener que estar ejecutando los comandos manualmente, o bien podés crear accesos directos con los comandos anteriores para facilitar el proceso.